# Installing and configuring a multi-node Hadoop cluster

Tags: hadoop, installation, cluster-computing

I am a newbee to Big Data systems having completed a few Coursera certifications. I plan to have my own personal Hadoop cluster using 4 commodity grade PCs. Currently all run Windows, but I am ok to install Linux on them. I searched a lot on the internet for the setup process, but found none(found many to spin on AWS). At this time, I am not restricted to any platform, but would like all the tech to be free \ open source. With 4 PCs I can have 1 master node and other 3 data nodes. Would appreciate detailed steps (at least the broad contours) on how to spin this bare metal Hadoop cluster.

Comment: If you want an easy setup, you can use Apache Ambari (from Hortonworks or MapR) or use Cloudera Manager

Comment: Thx Cricket_007. Is Cloudera installation on a multi node cluster free for personal use?

Comment: Cloudera Express is the free version. https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/latest/topics/cm_faqs.html#topic_1_0__section_nrr_wwv_ls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to install hadoop setup on 4-node cluster!

Requirement: 1 master 3 slaves (installation of hadoop setup on multiple node cluster)

---

Step 1: Get rid of windows. Currently Hadoop is available for Linux machines. You can have ubuntu 14.04 or later versions (or CentOS, Redhat etc)

Step 2: Install and setup Java
    $ sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
    $ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ferramroberto/java
    $ sudo apt-get update
    $ sudo apt-get install sun-java6-jdk

```
# Select Sun's Java as the default on your machine.
# See 'sudo update-alternatives --config java' for more information.    
#
$ sudo update-java-alternatives -s java-6-sun
```

Step 3: Set the path in .bashrc file (open this file using text editor(vi/nano) and append the below text)

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/jdk1.7.0_71
export PATH=PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
```

Step 4: Add a dedicated user (While that’s not required it is recommended)

```
# useradd hadoop 
# passwd hadoop
```

Step 5: Edit hosts file in /etc/ folder on all nodes, specify the IP address of each system followed by their host names.( open the file in using `vi /etc/hosts` and append the text below --

```
<ip address of master node> hadoop-master 
<ip address of slave node 1> hadoop-slave-1 
<ip address of slave node 2> hadoop-slave-2
<ip address of slave node 3> hadoop-slave-3
```

Step 6: Setup ssh in every node such that they can communicate with one another without any prompt for password.

```
$ su hadoop
$ ssh-keygen -t rsa 
$ ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub hadoop@hadoop-master 
$ ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub hadoop_tp1@hadoop-slave-1 
$ ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub hadoop_tp2@hadoop-slave-2
$ ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub hadoop_tp3@hadoop-slave-3
$ chmod 0600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys 
$ exit
```

for more information on SSH go to : [https://www.ssh.com/ssh/][1]

Step 7: In master server download and install Hadoop.

```
# mkdir /opt/hadoop 
# cd /opt/hadoop/ 
# wget http://apache.mesi.com.ar/hadoop/common/hadoop-1.2.1/hadoop-
  1.2.0.tar.gz 
# tar -xzf hadoop-1.2.0.tar.gz 
# mv hadoop-1.2.0 hadoop
# chown -R hadoop /opt/hadoop 
# cd /opt/hadoop/hadoop/
```

Installation is finished here!

Next step is : Configuring Hadoop

Step 1: Open core-site.xml and edit it as below :

```
<configuration>
<property> 
  <name>fs.default.name</name> 
  <value>hdfs://hadoop-master:9000/</value> 
</property> 
<property> 
  <name>dfs.permissions</name> 
  <value>false</value> 
</property> 
</configuration>
```

Step 2: open hdfs-site.xml and edit it as below :

```
<configuration>
<property> 
  <name>dfs.data.dir</name> 
  <value>/opt/hadoop/hadoop/dfs/name/data</value> 
  <final>true</final> 
</property> 

<property> 
  <name>dfs.name.dir</name> 
  <value>/opt/hadoop/hadoop/dfs/name</value> 
  <final>true</final> 
</property> 
 <property> 
  <name>dfs.name.dir</name> 
  <value>/opt/hadoop/hadoop/dfs/name</value> 
  <final>true</final> 
</property> 

<property> 
  <name>dfs.replication</name> 
  <value>3</value> 
</property> 
</configuration>
```

Step 3: open mapred-site.xml and edit --

```
<configuration>
<property> 
  <name>mapred.job.tracker</name> 
  <value>hadoop-master:9001</value> 
</property> 
</configuration>
```

Step 4: Append below text in hadoop-env.sh

```
export JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk1.7.0_17 export 
HADOOP_OPTS=Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true export 
HADOOP_CONF_DIR=/opt/hadoop/hadoop/conf
```

Step 5: Configure master --

```
$ vi etc/hadoop/masters 
hadoop-master
```

Step 5: Install it on slave nodes as well --

```
# su hadoop 
$ cd /opt/hadoop 
$ scp -r hadoop hadoop-slave-1:/opt/hadoop 
$ scp -r hadoop hadoop-slave-2:/opt/hadoop
$ scp -r hadoop hadoop-slave-3:/opt/hadoop
```

Step 6: Configure slaves --

```
$ vi etc/hadoop/slaves
hadoop-slave-1 
hadoop-slave-2
hadoop-slave-3
```

Step 7: format the nodes (ONLY ONE TIME OTHERWISE ALL THE DATA WILL BE LOST PERMANENTLY)

```
# su hadoop 
$ cd /opt/hadoop/hadoop 
$ bin/hadoop namenode –format
```

You are all set!!

You can start the services as follows --

```
$ cd $HADOOP_HOME/sbin
$ start-all.sh
```

Comment: Great PyCodoop. Thanks for the detailed answer. I will start from here

Comment: Why are you using Hadoop 1.2, which is several years old?

Comment: Also, you used Java 6, then set Java home for Java 7. Both of which are EOL... You need to update your notes

Comment: Thank you for your concern. Upgrading/updating anything on a linux based system is no big deal. I focused on installation/configuration part.